# How to copy char to srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr

Tags: c, sockets, structure

I'm stuck how to copy this :

```
srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr = udp->address;
```

I know that are different types and that I can't copy them on this way, but I tried almost everything but without success, please help me to solve it

Comment: What *is* `srv_address` and `udp->address`?

Comment: I have found following in my older project `memmove(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_addr, server->h_length);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `inet_pton(AF_INET, udp->peer_address, &srv_address.sin_addr);`

> int inet_pton(int af, const char *src, void *dst);
>
> This function converts the character string src into a network address structure in the af address family, then copies the network address structure to dst. The af argument must be either AF_INET or AF_INET6.

or

`srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr(udp->peer_address);`

> in_addr_t inet_addr(const char *cp);
>
> The inet_addr() function converts the Internet host address cp from IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation into binary data in network byte order

Comment: But I must cut the address exactly from element structure udp->address , I can not explicitly give the address in brackets

Comment: what is your element structure format?

Comment: char peer_address[20];

Comment: you mean like this `char peer_address[20] = "127.0.0.1"`

Comment: no, I assign value when I got the address from recvfrom function: recvfrom(sd,buf,MAX_SIZE,0,(struct sockaddr *) &srv_addr, &addrlen)struct udp_connection udp; strcpy(udp_cln.peer_address,inet_ntoa(srv_addr.sin_addr));

Comment: use `memcpy` or `stncpy` instead of `strcpy`

Comment: I tried like this but I still did not succeed   strncpy(srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr,udp->peer_address,20); memcpy(srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr,udp->peer_address,20);

Comment: answer i given was working in my code see the full code in the link http://ideone.com/bsLPEV

Comment: You have inverse example of mine but with my parametars it does'n show error finally ! But another problem is that my address when I print it is now null ? 
memcpy(inet_ntoa(srv_address.sin_addr),udp->peer_address,sizeof(srv_address));
printf("Server address is %s\n",srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr);

Comment: make your question more clear and give some code.

Comment: Well the code is huge, I tried to explain the problem : I just want to copy udp->peer_address which is type of char[20], to srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr which is type struct sockaddr_in, because I need it in sendto function : sendto(udp->udp_sd, buf, pack_len, 0 , (struct sockaddr *)&srv_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)... I tried almost everything also statement from your code is the only that doesn't show errors but in that case printf shows null printf("Server address is %s\n",srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr); , I hope that you understand me now

Comment: can you able to print proper address using `printf("%s\n", udp->peer_address);`

Comment: Yes I got the right IP

Comment: Then try with my new updated answer

Comment: Solved : srv_address.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr(udp->peer_address);

Comment: you know what `inet_addr(udp->peer_address)` this was my first answer but you said not working initially. This working mean my present updated answer also work. try and accept it.

Comment: yes I see, but when I was trying it didn't work, probabbly I wrote something wrong or something else was written, sorry this confused me I was stuck but thank you for patient and explanations it helped me

Comment: Accept the answer if it was useful.